# Clang Format incorrectly adds linebreak when using inline lambda in function call

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm seeing weird behavior with clang-format-14, where it's adding a linebreak on lines with inline lambdas being passed as a function argument. However, for whatever reason, it only does so if there is an argument after the lambda.

This is a minimal C++ example:

```cpp
#include <functional>

void foo(int x, const std::function<void()>&f) {
    f();
}

void bar(int x, const std::function<void()>& f, int y) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    foo(0, []() {});
    bar(0, []() {}, 0);
}
```

After running clang-format, this is the formatted code:

```cpp
#include <functional>

void foo(int x, const std::function<void()>& f) {
    f();
}

void bar(int x, const std::function<void()>& f, int y) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    foo(0, []() {});
    bar(
        0, []() {}, 0);
}
```

As you can see, the formatted changes don't even change the line length!

Also, this is my `.clang-format` file (run with clang-format version `Ubuntu clang-format version 14.0.6`):

```
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
ColumnLimit: 95
UseTab: Always
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AccessModifierOffset: -4
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:  "\".+\""
    Priority:   1
  - Regex:  "<[^/]+>"
    Priority:   2
  - Regex:  "<.+(?:\\.h|\\.hpp)>"
    Priority:   3
IndentCaseLabels: true
PointerAlignment: Left
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
```

How can I make clang format not add a line break here? I've experimented with the lambda-related flags like `AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine`, but those don't fix anything.

Comment: The bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45141

Comment: Some would say that's the correct formatting (not me though). Opinion based.